# Mysql 5.7.29 installation on Ubuntu Linux 18.04 LTS

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04

I'm re-installing MySQL (5.7.29) for Ubuntu Linux 18.04 LTS. I installed the package using apt & started the service without issue. I was not asked for a root password during the install and am not able to login.

I assume (from dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/default-privileges.html) that the data directory was initialized without my knowledge.

I used `$tail /var/log/mysql/error.log -n 50` to see if an initial random pwd was created - no luck.

I also tried `$mysql -u root --skip-password`, which also fails due to access denial.

It's been a couple of years since I've used MySQL. What am I doing wrong? TY!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu let the user login with the root account, this beahavior is default on MariaDB installations too:

```
sudo su -
mysql
```

If this don't resolve, you can start mysql without the tables associated with authentication:

```sh
sudo su -
systemctl stop mysql
mysqld --user mysql --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 --protocol tcp mysql -e "ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword'"
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 --protocol tcp -e 'shutdown'
systemctl start mysql
```

And try again ;)

Comment: 1) mysqld works if I prefix the cmndline with sudo

2) mysql -e "...." fails with error code 2002 - can't connect via socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Comment: Specify --protocol tcp, looks the updated version (v2...)

Comment: same result. i'm giving up for the night.